# issues in php while running it in run time

Tags: php

With great difficulty i was able to finish a project, however i get this error -

> PHP: Undefined offset 1

error, although my code is correct(i think).

Can you please help me in finding what is the mistake am doing...

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= count($res1); $i++) {
    for ($j = 1; $j <= count($res); $j++) {
        if ($res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] == $res['LIEFERANT'][$j]) {
            echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] = TRUE;
            echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$j] = TRUE;
        } else {
            echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] = FALSE;
            echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$j] = FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs at `if` condition.
Please help in finding the error.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: What values does $res1 and $res have?

Comment: The error is quite clear, the offset `1` of `$res1['LIEFERANT']` or `$res['LIEFERANT']` is not defined. How is your array defined ? Also you can var_dump it to see the content, might help.

Comment: can we have an example of what's in your arrays? one obvious thing though, if you use `[$i]` on `$res1['LIEFERANT']`, you should use `count($res1['LIEFERANT'])` instead of `count($res1)`, or maybe did you inverse keys and should use `$res1[$i]['LIEFERANT']`?

Comment: @Muhammad - $query1 = "Select LIEFERANT1 AS LIEFERANT FROM NVESCANNEN WHERE LIEFERANT2 = '".$lieferant."' UNION ALL Select LIEFERANT2 AS LIEFERANT FROM NVESCANNEN WHERE LIEFERANT1 = '".$lieferant."'";
            $row = oci_fetch_all($stid,$res);
$query2 = "SELECT DISTINCT LIEFERANT FROM SVBKOPF WHERE ID IN (SELECT BID FROM SVBDETAIL WHERE NVE0 = '".$_SESSION['nvenummer']."')";
      $res1 = array($stid);
      $row = oci_fetch_all($stid,$res1);

Comment: @Jules - $res1 is the result of the query1 "Select LIEFERANT1 AS LIEFERANT FROM NVESCANNEN WHERE LIEFERANT2 = '".$lieferant."' UNION ALL Select LIEFERANT2 AS LIEFERANT FROM NVESCANNEN WHERE LIEFERANT1 = '".$lieferant."'"; and $res is the result of query2 - "SELECT DISTINCT LIEFERANT FROM SVBKOPF WHERE ID IN (SELECT BID FROM SVBDETAIL WHERE NVE0 = '".$_SESSION['nvenummer']."')";

Comment: Quite unreadable, can you edit the question ?

Comment: if result of a query using fetch_assoc, then you definetly switched the keys, first is the row, second is the table column: use `$res1[$i]['LIEFERANT']`. By the way, i think you should count from 0: `for($i=0; $i<count($res1); $i++)`. Finally, i don't know what your code exactly does, but the logic might be flawed here, by comparing rows from `$res1` with EVERY row from `$res` to detect a change, strong chance you get false each time because you override the value. Only chance to get true is if the last row from `$res` matches..

Comment: @Kaddath - I tried but it still gives me undefined offset error from 0 to n

Comment: @jules - i get this undefined offset 0 error for the below code -----------for($i=0; $i<=count($res1); $i++)
         {
         for($j=0; $j<=count($res); $j++)
          {
       if ($res1[$i]['LIEFERANT'] == $res[$j]['LIEFERANT'])
       {
          echo $res1[$i]['LIEFERANT'] = TRUE;
          echo $res[$j]['LIEFERANT'] = TRUE;
       }
       else{
        echo $res1[$i]['LIEFERANT'] = FALSE;
        echo $res[$j]['LIEFERANT'] = FALSE; 
       }
       } 
         }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `$i` variable as an index of `$res1` which has `count($res1)` elements. The problem is that `$i` can be equal to `count($res1)` but array indexes are 0-based. The same goes for `$j` and `$res`. I think this should work better:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($res1); $i++)
{
  for($j=0; $j<count($res); $j++)
  {
    if ($res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] == $res['LIEFERANT'][$j])
    {
      echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] = TRUE;
      echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$j] = TRUE;
    }
    else{
      echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$i] = FALSE;
      echo $res1['LIEFERANT'][$j] = FALSE; 
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: That actually solved my error!!thanks dude :)

Comment: thanks for all the help guys!! :)

Comment: @Auto123  still foreach is much better option. check my edited solution

Comment: Still `foreach()` is much better option